# If statement not catching NaN

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I'm working on my first Javascript HTML application. Now I would like to introduce a if statement. However, this is not working. Could somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Many thanks in advance

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    label {
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: normal 16px ventura;
    color: white  
    }
    .button{
    width: 95px;
    font: normal 16px ventura;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
    .print{
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px; 
    var x = document.getElementById("Vectorlength").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
</style>
<body bgcolor= "#119ed8">
    <form id="form1">
        <p><label for="Vectorlength">Vector length (bp):</label> 
        <input type="text" name="Vectorlength" value="" />
        </p>
        <p><label for="Vectormass">Vector mass (ng):</label> 
        <input type="text" name="Vectormass" value="" />
        </p>
        <p><label for="Vectorconcentration">Vector concentration (ng/µL):</label> 
        <input type="text" name="Vectorconcentration" value="" />
        </p>
        <p><label for="Insertlength">Insert length (bp):</label> 
        <input type="text" name="Insertlength" value="" />
        </p>
        <p><label for="Insertconcentration ">Insert concentration (ng/µL):</label> 
        <input type="text" name="Insertconcentration" value="" />
        </p>
        <p><label for="Ratio">Ratio Insert/Vector:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="Ratio" value="3" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <button onclick="outputname()">Submit</button>
    <script>
        function outputname() {
            var x,y,name,a,b,answer, L,M;
            x=document.getElementById("form1") ;
            L=x.elements["Vectorlength"].value;
            M=x.elements["Vectormass"].value;
            C=x.elements["Vectorconcentration"].value;
            iL=x.elements["Insertlength"].value;
            iC=x.elements["Insertconcentration"].value;
            R=x.elements["Ratio"].value;

            y=Number(L)+Number(M);

            if (y==NaN)
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+=" is not valid! <br>";

            else
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=+y+"<br>";
        }
    </script>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is JavaScript not java

Comment: I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Comment: There is a JavaScript statement in your CSS...?!

Comment: Also explain your concrete error. What happens different from what you expect?

Comment: you can't put javascript code inside the style tag. write javascript code inside <script></script>  tags

Comment: As DaDaDom stated above, you've got JavaScript executing in your CSS section. JavaScript will only execute within the <script> tag. It looks like you're wanting to assign the value of those input fields to a variable so they'll be available on clicking the Submit button.

I would suggest maybe looking at an event similar to your "onclick" for submit and applying it so that it fires when the field is changed (or exited). "onchange" is an event that should fire when the user changes the input field.

Answer (score 3):

I have a working jsfiddle for your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/hyLL7t1v/1/

I have fixed the isNaN comparison:

```
if (isNaN(y)) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " is not valid! <br>";
} else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y+"<br>";
}
```

A few points to note here:

1. Js fiddle is set to run on DOM is ready. Since you have many interactions with the DOM I would suggest wrapping your javascript within a DOMReady function. Alternatively loading it as script tag or external file as the last line in the body would also work the same way.
2. If you check anything against NaN it will return false, including NaN.
   See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN
3. Please do not put javascript within style tag. That will throw an error.

I have also removed the javascript from inside the style tag.

Answer (score 0):

use global isNaN() function

```
if (isNaN(y)) { ... }
```

[info on the isNaN() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)